# How to "re-tame" my captive shingleback

Tags: behavior, reptiles, lizards, domestication

I have had my pet shingleback for a few years now, kept in an inside enclosure. I purchased the lizard of a breeder who had frequently handled the lizard and had it well tamed.

For the first 12 months that I had the lizard I would commonly take it out of its enclosure and hold it, or let it walk around the house while watching tv on rainy days or outside in the sun on sunny days. Slowly the lizard was handled less often, and the only human interaction it would get was when I would feed it.

Now, almost 2 years later, my lizard is very panicky when I put my hand in its enclosure, even when I just place its food bowl down, and it will not let me pick it up, always hissing, trying to bite or running away (or to in an attempt to bite).

As stated above, the lizard was already tamed when I purchased it.

I have no experience in taming reptiles, so how would I go about making my lizard more comfortable around people and allow people to pet and pick it up?

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!